Integration-Test: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
I want to create a integration test against a database and clean it up afterwards in an wildfly/arquillian environment. But when I try to execute the Test I get a Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor. I use junit and I implemented following code according to this site for my Integration Test:
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyFirstIT{


    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
            .addClasses(EntityManager.class)
            .addAsManifestResource(
                EmptyAsset.INSTANCE,
                ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager myEntityManager;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setup() {...}

    @Test
    public void createInstanceTest() {

        // ... Testing Code redacted
        // ...

        var myClass = myEntityManager.find(MyClass.class ,"1");
    }
}

My beans.xml is defined as:
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>

My pom,xml includes:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-elytron-util</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-testng-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

This configuration doesn't seem to work. I don't know what I am missing, what I might need to add, if I'm doing something wrong or if this is not possible at all.
Other people seem to have had the same problem but the post is from 2014. Maybe the solution is deprecated?
I would appreciate any help.

What container are you testing on? You've got a dependency on arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1, but you've also got dependencies on WildFly and you've tagged the question with "wildfly".

My approach is a little bit wild, since I have no other option with the budget I have. I want to test against a running local wildfly application that is connected to a database. Simply put, I am confused and have no idea what I'm doing since there is outdated documentation that I try to work through. All I want is to clean up the mess that I test against, e.g. I persist an object and test the response. Afterwards I want to clean up by deleting that object, so I can repeat the test. Therefore, I want to inject an entitymanager/dao but I can't even setup arquillian properly.

Have a look at https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy-examples/tree/main/contacts. This is for Jakarta EE 10, but you should just need to downgrade some components. I've written that example, so feel free to ping me if you've got more questions.

The org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom version you are using is from 2017 - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.arquillian/arquillian-bom - while the org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-core is recent. So the classpath misalignment is very likely the culprit.
Also, obtain complete stacktraces and try running maven with -X,--debug for more debug information.

Thank you, I have indeed an unnecessary arquillian dependency. Removing this doesn't cause the error anymore and I get another error . I think that answers the stackoverflow question, but I am no where near solving my problem to setup arquillian

Excellent, I will keep my eyes peeled for your next post! I hope it involves Jakarta EE and JUnit 5 and such :-)
